# SQL select specific group from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named **trades** like this:

```
id      trade_date      trade_price     trade_status    seller_name
1       2015-01-02      150             open            Alex
2       2015-03-04      500             close           John
3       2015-04-02      850             close           Otabek
4       2015-05-02      150             close           Alex
5       2015-06-02      100             open            Otabek
6       2015-07-02      200             open            John
```

I want to sum up `trade_price` grouped by `seller_name` when last (by `trade_date`) `trade_status` was 'open'. That is:

```
sum_trade_price     seller_name     
700                 John
950                 Otabek
```

The rows where `seller_name` is **Alex** are skipped because the last `trade_status` was **'close'**.
Although I can get desirable output result with the help of **nested select**

```
SELECT SUM(t1.trade_price), t1.seller_name
WHERE t1.seller_name NOT IN 
                (SELECT t2.seller_name FROM trades t2 
                    WHERE t2.seller_name = t1.seller_name AND t2.trade_status = 'close' 
                    ORDER BY t2.trade_date DESC LIMIT 1)
from trades t1
group by t1.seller_name
```

**But** it takes **more than 1 minute** to execute above query (I have approximately 100K rows).
**Is there another way to handle it?**
I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: correlated `Not exists` vs `not in` might be faster. `Not exists` allows early exit once a single occurrence is found. not in has to process all records I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this with window functions:

```
SELECT SUM(t.trade_price), t.seller_name
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             FIRST_VALUE(trade_status) OVER (PARTITION BY seller_name ORDER BY trade_date desc) as last_trade_status
      FROM trades t
     ) t
WHERE last_trade_status <> 'close;
GROUP BY t.seller_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should perform reasonably with an index on `seller_name`

```
select
    sum(trade_price) as sum_trade_price,
    seller_name
from
    trades
    inner join
    (
        select distinct on (seller_name) seller_name, trade_status
        from trades
        order by seller_name, trade_date desc
    ) s using (seller_name)
where s.trade_status = 'open'
group by seller_name
```